# External display resolution is broken after wake on M1

Tags: display, sleep-wake, thunderbolt, resolution

on my MacMini M1 I have the following problem:

Very often (not always) when macOS (11.2.2) wakes up after some sleep time, the resolution on my main display (BenQ EW3270U) is broken in a very weird way:

[image]

The box on the right side is part of my second display.

The display is connected via Thunderbolt. Before the M1 I had a MacBook Pro 2014 and never had a problem with the display. But to be honest: I cant remember if the problem started with the M1 or if it was introduced by some macOS update.

The only thing that helps is changing the resolution scaling setting to something else and then switching back to my usual scaling setting

[image]

Questions:

- Anybody recognises this behaviour and knows how to fix it?
- As a work around: does anyone know how to automate / script changing the resolution scaling setting?

Comment: I deleted my 'answer' because it referred to ultrawides and your monitor is a standard 16:9. Sorry.